# AngularJS ng-pattern - 1 or 2 numbers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angularjs-directive

In the code below I need to get the `ng-pattern` to receive 1 or 2 numbers, the format being in minutes, that is, minimum 0 or 00 and maximum 59.

```
<input type="text" step="any" value="" ng-model="job.valueIntervalo" 
       min="0" max="60" ng-pattern="/^([0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}$/">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
<input type="text" step="any" value="" ng-model="job.valueIntervalo"
       min="0" max="60" ng-pattern="/^[0-5]{1}[0-9]{1}$/">
```

Comment: Tks... Perfect solution,congratulation!